# Print all strings of array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, printing

Very new to Java and programming in  general. trying to figure out how to print the contents of my array

```
public class GameClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String [] gameList = new String [] {"Call of Duty", "Skyrim", "Overwatch", "GTA", "Castlevania", "Resident Evil", "HALO", "Battlefield", "Gears of War", "Fallout"};
        System.out.println(gameList[]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is an array, not arraylist. Arrays are created `new Type[size]` while lists such as ArrayList via `new ArrayList<Type>()`. Arrays have fixed size while lists are resizable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `util` package for one line printing

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(gameList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick.

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i <gameList.length; i ++)
     System.out.print(gameList[i]+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate each element and print:

```
for(String s : gameList){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print out your array of games by using the following loop:

```
for(String game : gameList){
     System.out.println(game);
}
```

This runs through each item in your gameList array and prints it.